# Importing types from @types without corresponding library

Tags: typescript, google-ads-script

Sorry if the question is unclear but I don't know how else to put it. I have a Google Ads Script project that I develop in Typescript. I use BigQuery library. As you know in Google Ads you don't need to import any libraries (like in Node.js) because they are already available in global scope.

So I only need to import types from https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/google-apps-script. It works in the way that it cancels any errors saying that BigQuery is not defined etc. But can I import and use any particular interfaces?

For example I have a function that returns `TableFieldSchema`.

```
const bqQuerySchemaGenerator = (description: string, name: string, type: string) => {
    const nameFieldSchema : any = BigQuery.newTableFieldSchema();
    nameFieldSchema.description = description;
    nameFieldSchema.name = name;
    nameFieldSchema.type = type;
    return nameFieldSchema
}
```

I would like to define a type that would show me what this function returns. I know that normally if I was using a corresponding library I would import something like

```
import {TableFieldSchema} from "google-apps-script"
```

But as I mentioned I don't use any external library so instead I would imagine something like this

```
import type {TableFieldSchema} from "@types/google-apps-script"

const bqQuerySchemaGenerator = (description: string, name: string, type: string) : TableFieldSchema => {
    const nameFieldSchema : any = BigQuery.newTableFieldSchema();
    nameFieldSchema.description = description;
    nameFieldSchema.name = name;
    nameFieldSchema.type = type;
    return nameFieldSchema
}
```

but it doesn't work. How can I import these types? Or is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've installed the types package that you mentioned:

```txt
npm install --save-dev @types/google-apps-script
```

then you should be able to access the types (without an `import` statement) using the `GoogleAppsScript` [namespace](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/namespaces.html) on the [global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis), just like you can access the values you showed (e.g. the `BigQuery` object):

```ts
const bqQuerySchemaGenerator = (description: string, name: string, type: string): GoogleAppsScript.BigQuery.Schema.TableFieldSchema => {
  const nameFieldSchema = BigQuery.newTableFieldSchema();
  nameFieldSchema.description = description;
  nameFieldSchema.name = name;
  nameFieldSchema.type = type;
  return nameFieldSchema;
};
```

Alternatively, you can also alias any type if you plan to reuse it. That way you won't have to type the full namespace path every time:

```ts
type TableFieldSchema = GoogleAppsScript.BigQuery.Schema.TableFieldSchema;

const bqQuerySchemaGenerator = (description: string, name: string, type: string): TableFieldSchema => {
  const nameFieldSchema = BigQuery.newTableFieldSchema();
  nameFieldSchema.description = description;
  nameFieldSchema.name = name;
  nameFieldSchema.type = type;
  return nameFieldSchema;
};
```